# Javascript code work in Chrome but in IE is executed at the end of all instruction

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have a code inside of a click event and the js instruction are not executing until everything finish.

```
$('#elementID').off('click').on('click', function() 
{
  $('#objToChange').css({ 'color': 'red', 'font-size': '150%' });
  someFuction();
  anotherFunction();
});
```

This work perfect in Firefox and Chrome, but in IE doesn't do it. I mean he made the change of the color at the end of the execution of the hole code and I need that the change take place just in the moment that I made the jquery change.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a difference in the way different browsers render things.  If you add a slight delay between the css update and the rest of the code it should be fine...

```
$('#elementID').off('click').on('click', function() {
    $('#objToChange').css({ 'color': 'red', 'font-size': '150%' });

    // wrap the rest of the code in a setTimeout with a small delay
    setTimeout(function() {
        someFuction();
        anotherFunction();
    }, 10);
});
```

Note: Some people say `setTimeout` with a delay of zero is good enough, but I've seen that fail so always use at least 1ms delay.  10ms is more than enough, but still not a visible pause.